# MS Access vba code error with visible invisible VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a filed called application. I have written code in vba to make the other field "application_txt" field visible and invisible if a particular value from application field is selected. But for this particulat field application when I write the below code in vba it throws the error. I dont understand why. It works fine for the other fields. Below is the code:

Can anyone please help me with this problem. Is it allowed to give application as field name in MS Access.

Many thanks,
Kiran Chapidi

```
This is not working:
Private Sub application_Click()
If application.Value = "5= others" Then
    Me.application_txt.Visible = True
Else
    Me.application_txt.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

This is working fine:

```
Private Sub Design_Click()
If Design.Value = "3= others" Then
   Me.design_txt.Visible = True
Else
   Me.design_txt.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Name it something else. [`Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application) is the Access application.

Comment: Thank you BigBen, I thought so too, thank you for the confirmation